# Car generation algorithm

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have an algorithm which generates some cars (quote unquote) and displays them using Graphics. I would like to know if my code is using Random correctly, and if it has any memory leaks. Or if there is anything I did wrong and I should improve.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    public Random rand;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rand = new Random();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();

        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            Car car = new Car();
            Body body = GenerateBody();
            car.body = body;
            car.name = GenerateName();
            car.tires = GenerateTires(body.edges.ToArray());
            //DrawCar(car);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(car);           
            i++;
        } while (i < 20);
    }

    private Body GenerateBody()
    {

        int amountOfEdges = rand.Next(2, 6); 
        int i = 0;
        List<PointF> edges = new List<PointF>();
        edges.Add(new PointF(256, 256)); //PointF of first edge of the polygon, so the body is created
        do
        {
            PointF newPointF = new PointF(rand.Next(-60, 61) + edges.Last().X, rand.Next(-60, 61) + edges.Last().Y);
            //Use last element to create a new polygon relative to last PointF, and change the coords by a random value 
            //between 1 and 20
            edges.Add(newPointF);
            i++;
        } while (i < amountOfEdges);
       //             
       //Give our car a random color
        Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(200, rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256));
        return new Body(randomColor, edges);
    }

    private CarTire[] GenerateTires(PointF[] edges)
    {
        int tires = rand.Next(1, edges.Length + 1); //Tire amount is random from 1 to edge length. Each tire has the position of the corresponding edge.
        List<CarTire> tirelist = new List<CarTire>();
        int i = 0;
        do
        {

            //Create a random tire
            CarTire t = new CarTire(Color.FromArgb(255, rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256)), rand.Next(10, 20), edges[i]);
            tirelist.Add(t);

            i++;
        } while (i < tires);
        return tirelist.ToArray();
    }
    private string GenerateName()
    {
        int length = rand.Next(5, 12);
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyz";
        do
        {
            sb.Append(charset[rand.Next(0, charset.Length)]);
            i++;
        } while (i < length);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private void DrawCar(Car c)
    {
        //Draw tires first, so body is on top

        foreach (CarTire t in c.tires)
        {
                Rectangle r = getCircle(t.location, t.radius);
                g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(t.color), r);

        }

        //Draw the body
        g.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(c.body.color), c.body.edges.ToArray());

    }
    private Rectangle getCircle(PointF center, int radius)
    {
        return new Rectangle((int)Math.Round(center.X - radius),(int)Math.Round(center.Y - radius), radius * 2, radius * 2);

    }
    class Car
    {

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }

        //A car needs tires and a body.
        public Body body;
        public CarTire[] tires;
        public string name;     
    }
    class Body
    {
        public Color color;
        public List<PointF> edges = new List<PointF>();
        public Body(Color carColor,List<PointF> bodyEdges)
        {
            color = carColor;
            edges = bodyEdges;
        }
    }
    class CarTire
    {
        public Color color;
        public int radius;
        public PointF location;
        public CarTire(Color tirecolor, int tireradius,PointF position)
        {
            color = tirecolor;
            radius = tireradius;
            location = position;
        }
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g.Clear(ActiveForm.BackColor);
        DrawCar((Car)comboBox1.SelectedItem);


        }
}
}
```

Button1 is a button with label "Generate some cars", it generates some cars and puts them in the combo box.

Here is a gif of the cars generated:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> g = ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
> ```

This is bad. The old or previous `Graphics` object needs to be disposed before you create a new one but even so using a global `Graphics` object is still bad.

You should override the `OnPaint` method and do the drawing there.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;

    // drawing...       
}
```

Pass the `Graphics` object to all drawing methods and call them from `OnPaint`

```
private void DrawCar(Graphics g, Car c)
{
    // draw the car..,
}
```

---

> ```
> g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(t.color), r)
> ```

This is bad too. When working with `Graphics` nearly everything needs to be disposed so does the `SolidBrush`. The right way to use it is like this

```
using(var sb = new SolidBrush(t.color))
{
    g.FillEllipse(sb, r);
}
```

---

But not everything is bad. You wrote classes for the car, for the body and tires. Your methods have only a single responsibility each. This is all good. From the design point of view you now should put them in appropriate classes that have a single responsibility too similar to what [@chenop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/152625/59161) suggested in his answer. You're on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

I would expect separating the UI interactions, the drawing actions and the generating car actions.

- `AppManager` - The Application Manager
- `CarGenerator` - The class which resposible to generate a car and its properties
- `DrawingManager` - The class which responsible for drawing something, it is the only class that consume the graphics class.

So I suggest the following:
[image]

Comment: Me curious. What tool did you create this diagram with?

Comment: @t3chb0t Created via http://plantuml.com it can  be used also as an addon inside google doc - great for writing design docs.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plantuml-gizmo/gkhhgpmifdpiagjagcbconfnnhkmomnp

Answer (score 2):

Default of Random is 0

`rand.Next(0, 6)` same as `rand.Next(6)`

Can initialize like this `public Random rand = new Random();`

I think this is cleaner for a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
}
```

Public is typically Capital